# SQLite LIKE statement and escaping characters

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-like

I need to delete database entries where the key contains a certain string.

The SearchString before escaping:

```
EntityCollection(Id='INST_PAT_ID%200100010050057716')
```

Escaping code:

```
logger.debug("wildCard: " + wildCard);
String escapedString = wildCard.replace("%", "\\%");
String escapedString2 = escapedString.replace("'", "\\'");
String escapedString3 = escapedString2.replace("_", "\\_");
logger.debug("escapedString3: " + escapedString3);
```

The SearchString after escaping:

```
EntityCollection(Id=\''INST\_PAT\_ID\%200100010050057716\'')%'' {escape '\'}' in key.
```

The SQL Statement looks like this.

```
final String where = "key LIKE ?";
final String[] args = new String[] { DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("'%" + escapedString3 + "%'" + " {escape '\\'}") };
int success = database.delete(CacheDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, where, args);

logger.debug("Delete attempt affected " + success + " lines!");
logger.debug("Deleted all cache entries from database containing: " + args[0] + " in key.");
```

However I cannot get it to work, because it generates the wrong SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `?` in your query, it's parameterised. You are not using concatenation (it seems), so you don't need to worry about escaping characters. Just use the raw string. However, since there are no `%` characters in the `where`, your query is the equivalent of using `=`.

Comment: int success = database.delete(CacheDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, "KEY LIKE ?", new String[] { wildCard });
  logger.debug("Delete attempt affected " + success + " lines!"); EntityCollection(Id='INST_PAT_ID%200100010050057716')
 - Delete attempt affected 0 lines!